# ToggleSwitch not calling IsEnabledChanged

Tags: c#, uwp, toggle

I have my toggleswitch:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Enabled" OnContent="1" OffContent="2" IsOn="True" IsEnabledChanged="ToggledEnable"/>
```

Which is supposed to trigger ToggledEnable:

```
    private void ToggledEnable(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Enabled.IsEnabled)
        {
            //Other stuff
        } else
        {
            //Other stuff
        }
    }
```

but that does not happen. According to debug this function is never called. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Toggled event which is fired when the toggle is On/Off.

IsEnabledChanged is fired when you disable or enable the control, disabled=“grayed out”, when a control is disabled user cannot interact with the control.